# Extract list parts in a vectorized way with plyr::mutate?

Tags: r, list, plyr

Suppose this code:

```
foo <- data.frame(cols_val=c("NA", "1:2:3", "4:5:6"))
library(plyr)
foo <- mutate(
  foo,
  cols_list = str_split(cols_val, ":"),
  one = cols_list[1],
  two = cols_list[2])
```

I would like `foo$one` to be `c(NA, "1", "4")` and `foo$two` to be `c(NA, "2", "5")`. That is, to split out the values of `cols_val` into individual columns of the data frame.

However, `cols_list` is a list, and `one == cols_list[1]` is the first element of that list (`== cols_list[[1]]`), while `two == cols_list[1]`. So, I don't know how to vectorize this properly.

Help?

```
> foo
  cols_val cols_list one     two
1       NA        NA  NA 1, 2, 3
2    1:2:3   1, 2, 3  NA 1, 2, 3
3    4:5:6   4, 5, 6  NA 1, 2, 3

> str(foo$cols_list)
List of 3
 $ : chr "NA"
 $ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
 $ : chr [1:3] "4" "5" "6"
```

Comment: Try `library(splitstackshape); cSplit(foo, 'cols_val', ":")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *plyr*, you can use `tidyr::separate()`.  It does exactly what you want to do.  We can keep the existing column (with `remove = FALSE`) as well as convert all the new columns to their appropriate type (with `convert = TRUE`). I only use `fill = "left"` to avoid a warning when it is not used.  I'm not really sure why the warning occurs.

```
tidyr::separate(foo, cols_val, c("one", "two", "three"), ":", 
    remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE, fill = "left")
#   cols_val one two three
# 1       NA  NA  NA    NA
# 2    1:2:3   1   2     3
# 3    4:5:6   4   5     6
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the warning occurs because the first row can't be split into three columns using :

Comment: Yeah.  The help file says it's something to do with `sep` but I tried `sep = rep(":", 2)` but that didn't get rid of it either.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(foo, 'cols_val', ":")
#     cols_val_1 cols_val_2 cols_val_3
#1:         NA         NA         NA
#2:          1          2          3
#3:          4          5          6
```

By default, the original column will be dropped as `drop=TRUE`.  If we also need to keep the original column, use `drop=FALSE`.  It also converts the 'class' by default

```
cSplit(foo, 'cols_val', ":", drop=FALSE)
#  cols_val cols_val_1 cols_val_2 cols_val_3
#1:       NA         NA         NA         NA
#2:    1:2:3          1          2          3
#3:    4:5:6          4          5          6
```